# Terraform planを実行するとエラーになる。（変数を呼び出せない？）

Tags: aws

## 解決したいこと

外部ファイルから変数を呼ぶ際のエラーをなくしたい

## 事象

`terraform plan`を実行すると下記エラーが出現。。。

**エラー内容**

```
$ terraform plan    
Error: Error loading Desktop\terraform\network.tf: Error reading config for 
aws_internet_gateway[${var.GW_NAME}]: parse error at 1:11: expected "}" but 
found invalid sequence "$"
```

## やりたいこと

- variable.tf、prod.tfvarsに定義した変数をnetwork.tfが読み込む。
- prod.tfvarsの変数を編集すれば、VPC名やCIDRブロックを任意の値に変更できるようにしたい。
- ゆくゆくはstg.tfvars, dev.tfvarsを作成し、`terraform apply -var-file=dev.tfvars`で環境毎にvar-fileを変えることで、各環境を作成したい。

## 構成

```
$ ls -l
total 34
-rw-r--r-- 1 takahashi.kazuki 197121 1298 2月  14 17:52 network.tf　★ネットワーク設定用
-rw-r--r-- 1 takahashi.kazuki 197121 1536 2月  14 17:48 prod.tfvars　★本番環境用変数
-rw-r--r-- 1 takahashi.kazuki 197121  149 2月  14 15:53 provider.tf　★プロバイダー情報
-rw-r--r-- 1 takahashi.kazuki 197121  484 2月  14 15:53 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 takahashi.kazuki 197121 1425 2月  14 15:53 variables.tf
```

## 対象ファイルの中身

### network.tf

```
$ cat network.tf
resource "aws_vpc" "${var.VPC_NAME}" {
    cidr_block = "${var.VPC_CIDR}"
    instance_tenancy = "default"
    enable_dns_support = "true"
    enable_dns_hostnames = "false"
    tags {
      Name = "${var.VPC_NAME}"
    }
}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "${var.GW_NAME}" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.${var.VPC_NAME}.id}"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "${var.SUBNET1_NAME}" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.${var.VPC_NAME}.id}"
    cidr_block = "${var.SUBNET1_CIDR}"
    availability_zone = "${var.SUBMET1_AZZONE}"
}

resource "aws_subnet" "${var.SUBNET2_NAME}" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.${var.VPC_NAME}.id}"
    cidr_block = "${var.SUBNET2_CIDR}"
    availability_zone = "${var.SUBNET2_AZZONE}"
}

resource "aws_route_table" "${var.INTERNET_ROUTE}" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.${var.VPC_NAME}.id}"
    route {
        cidr_block = "${var.INTERNET_ROUTE_CIDR}"
        gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.${var.GW_NAME}.id}"
    }
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "${var.SUBNET1_NAME}" {
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.${var.SUBNET1_NAME}.id}"
    route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.${var.INTERNET_ROUTE}.id}"
}

resource "aws_route_table_association" "${var.SUBNET2_NAME}" {
    subnet_id = "${aws_subnet.${var.SUBNET2_MAME}.id}"
    route_table_id = "${aws_route_table.${var.INTERNET_ROUTE}.id}"
    }
```

### prod.tfvars

```
$ cat prod.tfvars
########
##network.tf
VPC_NAME = "tf-test-network"
VPC_CIDR = "192.168.0.0/16"
GW_NAME = "tf-test-internet-gw"
SUBNET1_NAME = "prod-tf-test-subnet-1a"          #this subnet in ap-northeast-1a for Internet
SUBNET1_CIDR = "192.168.10.0/24"
SUBNET1_AZZONE = "ap-northeast-1a"
SUBNET2_NAME = "prod-tf-test-subnet-1c"          #this subnet in ap-northeast-1c for Internet
SUBNET2_CIDR = "192.168.110.0/24"
SUBNET2_AZZONE = "ap-northeast-1c"
INTERNET_ROUTE = "prod-tf-test-internet-route"
INTERNET_ROUTE_CIDR = "0.0.0.0/0"
```

### variables.tf

```
$ cat variables.tf
########
##network.tf
variable "VPC_NAME" {}
variable "VPC_CIDR" {}
variable "GW_NAME" {}
variable "SUBNET1_NAME" {}         #this subnet in ap-northeast-1a for Internet
variable "SUBNET1_CIDR" {}
variable "SUBNET1_AZZONE" {}
variable "SUBNET2_NAME" {}         #this subnet in ap-northeast-1c for Internet
variable "SUBNET2_CIDR" {}
variable "SUBNET2_AZZONE" {}
variable "INTERNET_ROUTE" {}
variable "INTERNET_ROUTE_CIDR" {}
```

Answer (score 1):

下記部分で変数の入れ子が行われています（ `"${aws_internet_gateway.${var.GW_NAME}.id}"` ）が、

```
resource "aws_route_table" "${var.INTERNET_ROUTE}" {
    vpc_id = "${aws_vpc.${var.VPC_NAME}.id}"
    route {
        cidr_block = "${var.INTERNET_ROUTE_CIDR}"
        gateway_id = "${aws_internet_gateway.${var.GW_NAME}.id}"
    }
}
```

Terraformでは変数の入れ子は現在不可能なようです。
[nested variables, or 'Templatable' terraform module? · Issue #1114 · hashicorp/terraform](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/1114#issuecomment-303475977)

> It will not be possible to interpolate into variable names within interpolation expressions; this would add far too much dynamism and make it hard or impossible to do the graph analysis Terraform requires to do its work.